# Java: Reading the output of a method

Tags: java

I am using reflection to execute a method at runtime . However when the method does not return anything, I want to read the last line that was printed by the invoked method and store it in a String variable. Can somebody help me with this problem because I am in a total fix.
Currently I am doing it by using System.setOut. Is there a better way of doing this. Below is the code that I am currently using.

```
PrintStream originalOutStream = System.out; 
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("D:/myFile.txt")));
smething(2);// a method which prints something
System.setOut(originalOutStream);
FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream("D:/myFile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr));
String strLine;
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
.. Do the necessary processing
 }
```

Comment: please paste the sample code that you have tried.

Comment: You want to read the last line from STDOUT, right? I'm not sure if it is possible at all, but it has nothing to do with reflection, just I/O.

Comment: Are the methods you try to invoke known to you beforehand? Is it possible that methods neither print nor return anything?

Comment: I think you can store the last line into a temporary variable.If you find the method does not return anything,you get it from the temporary variable.

Comment: The method I am trying to invoke is not know to me. I am basically trying to create a tool in which the user is asked to input a code and the the methods are executed and their outputs are shown in the tool itself. If the methods return something, I just display the return value. However if the method is not returning anything, I want to display the final output of the method called. I am using Refection's method.invoke() to execute the method.

Comment: William Feirie : How do I store the last line in a temporary variable?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to wrap the method call inside another which temporarily changes the `System.out` stream and examine the outputs afterwards.

It should look like this:

```
void wrapper( /* Parameter list */) {
  /* change System.out
     call methods
     take System.out to previous state
  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off what I can understand, you want to return a string from a method. The best way to do this is by making a String method:

```
public String finalString = someString();
public String someString() {
  return "foo";
}
```

Please clarify your question and add code that you are using.

EDIT: Just the last thing that was printed to the console?

```
public class Foo {
  public String lastOut = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    lastString = "red " + Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    System.out.println(lastString);
  }
}
```

Maybe that sort of thing? Alternatively you could use an [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) and continue adding the last string sent to the deque. To me this seems like a more practical way of going about this, however this may not be what you are looking for...

-Cork

Comment: I am not trying to return a string from a method. I want to read the output of the method invoked.

Comment: Explain a little bit more. I'm not sure I understand what you're wanting?